# how to find login duration using hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop and have recently got familiar with MapReduce technique. It is impressive however I am an absolute beginner to workout resolution for a mapreduce problem. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. I have logical approach with me but don't know how to map it with hadoop.

Problem Description: I have to find Login Duration on each server in my organisation.
Inputs:
There are two tab separated value files provided as input with the following structure:

```
File1:
UserName Timestamp                    serverid
CMXO001  02-Jan-2014 12:00:00.234567  HP0012XP023
CMXO001  02-Jan-2014 12:10:20.234567  HP0012XP023
```

Above file contains a login and corressponding logout record which can be in any order in the input file.

```
File2:
ServerId    ServerName
HP0012XP023 HP XP Server London
```

We have to write hadoop mapreduce jobs to perform following:

1: Find out logins performed each day for each server [no need of server name]
Expected Output:
    Date       Server      LoginCount
    91-01-2014 HP0012XP023 1

2: Find out the total login time [ total connection time] for each user in the entire dataset for each server

```
expected output:
Date      ServerName          User    Durationfor that day
10/01/14  HP XP Server London CMXO001 10:20
```

3: Find our which users have kept login session connected for more than 1 hour atleast 5 times a month.

```
Expected output:
Username Times
CMXO001  12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are solutions for your 3 tasks:

1. Your Mappers work on File1. On each input record (row) Map function extracts day from the timestamp, and concatenates it with server to get the output key. The output value is 1, thus the output of the Mapper is (day-serverId, 1). Reducers just sum up values for each day-serverId - exactly like in Wordcount example (which is a "Hello World" for Hadoop - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v1.0).
2. Your Mappers work on File1. On each input record (row) Map function issues: key = UserName-Date-ServerId, value = Time. Reducers receive two time values for each key, calculate duration, and issue the expected output.
   How the Reducers translate ServerId to Server Name? You have to send File2 to Reducers using DistributedCache feature of Hadoop. Reducers will read this file in Setup function and keep the mapping in memory.
3. You use here a chain of two MapReduce jobs. First, you calculate login duration for each user, for each day, like you did in the task "2." The output will be the input for second MapReduce job. In the second job the Mappers will issue output like this: key = userId, value = 1 - but only for input record with duration > 1h. The Mappers will not issue any output for other records. The Reducers will do numeric summarisation exactly like in the task "1."

Comment: This sounds like a very good approach. I am going to try this out and provide feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help Evgeny, you have pointed in right direction. There were hiccups in using distributed cache and other functionality however it didn't stop fromm getting it done. Distributed Cache related functions are deprecated and not much help available on it or may be I am new :)

Comment: Distributed Cache is one of the most useful Hadoop MapReduce features. I guess you looked at org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache from the old Hadoop API. I recommend you to read about Distributed Cache in Hadoop Definitive Guide by Tom White (3rd edition!).